# What is the complexity time for calculating the height of avl tree?

Tags: time-complexity, avl-tree

given avl tree, what is the time-complexity of "best" algorithm for calculate the height of the tree?

I know that the height of the tree is log(n) given that exists n elements in the tree. But how can I calculate the height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the number of nodes that make a tree of height h is `N_h`. So the height of the tree having left child as the root is `h-1` having `N_(h-1)` nodes and the right subtree can have minimum height of `h - 2` with `N_(h-2)` nodes as the AVL tree is balanced ( height difference of left and right subtree cannot be more than 1).
We can write the formula as following

```
N_h = N_(h -1) + N_(h -2) + 1           (i)
```

The base cases are `N_1 = 1` and `N_2 = 2`
And

```
N_(h−1) = N_(h−2) + N_(h−3) + 1           (ii)
```

Putting `(ii)` in equation `(i)` we get

```
N_h = N_(h−2) + N_(h−3) + 1  + N_(h -2) + 1 
=> N_h = 2*N_(h−2) + N_(h−3) + 2 
=> N_h > 2*N_(h-2)
=> N_h > 2^(h/2)
=> log(N_h) > log(2^(h/2))
=> 2log(N_h) > h
=> h = O(log(N_h)
```

Replacing `N_h` by `n` we can write

```
h = O(lgn)
```